# how to manually write axis label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make show the proportions of 0-1 in different intervals, such as following:

```
df <- data.frame(num=20*abs(rnorm(100)), y=rbinom(100,1,0.5))
df$num <- cut(df$num, breaks = c(0,10,20,30,Inf))
ggplot(data=aggregate(df$y, by=list(df$num), mean),
              aes(x=Group.1,y=x))+geom_col()+ylim(0,1)
```

but I want to change labels on x axis with 0,10,20... just between bars.
How to rewrite axis labels with a different number of bars, or how to accomplish the whole progress by ggplot?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(num = str_extract(num, "\\d+")) %>% summarise(x = mean(y))  %>% ggplot(., aes(x = num, y = x)) + geom_col() + ylim(0, 1)`

Comment: add a line `df$num <- factor(df$num, labels=c(0,10,20,"inf"))` before running ggplot to custom the labels

Comment: thanks, it does make what I want. but how can I change the group into intervals with 10 instead of 1? @akrun

Comment: It is not clear from about the question

Comment: The question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can try this save you plot as an object and make sure that your x variable is categorical

```
df$num <- factor(df$num, labels=c(0,10,20,"inf"))

p + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("val1" = "0", "val2" = "10",
                              "val3" = "20", "val4" = "inf"))
```